# Function Ambiguation

Tags: function, fortran, ambiguous-call

I cannot understand how these two functions produce ambiguation.
If the types are changed to integer or real, the compiler does not
flag any ambiguation.

```
Function split_to_str_unidim  &
  (                           &
    a, delim, mold,           &
    pos                       &
  )                           &
    Result (bn)

  Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim, mold
  Character (len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos

  Character (len=65), Allocatable :: bn(:)

End Function


Function split_to_str        &
  (                          &
    a, delim, b1, b2,        &
    b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8,  & 
    pos                      &
  )                          &
    Result (b)

  Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim
  Character (len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos

  Character (len=*), Intent (out) :: b1, b2
  Character (len=*), Intent (out), Optional :: b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8
  Logical :: b

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A call such as

```
split_to_str(a,b,c,d)
```

where `a,b,c,d` are all strings can't be unequivocally identified with only one of your two functions.  That's ambiguous.

To disambiguate you'll have to make the signatures (the non-optional, intent(in) argument list) unique.  From your recent trail of Qs and As you've already discussed this with others, I have nothing to add to what has gone before.

I'm surprised that changing the type from `character(len=*)` to `real` or `integer` doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Any suggestion how this ambiguation can be resolved?

Comment: Don't put the two functions in an interface (which I assume you've done). Just call the appropriate one depending on the context.